# How can I open a licensed GPT chat like on https://chat.openai.com/ on my own user if I have an API key that is not from my user?

Tags: chatgpt, gpt, api

I can already ask questions against GPT4 with an API key that I got from a group license, see a question on my first tests at Stack Overflow [How do I run a GPT API shell command in Jupyter Notebook without having to put a multi-line string argument in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77888241/how-do-i-run-a-gpt-api-shell-command-in-jupyter-notebook-without-having-to-put-a/). But I do not know how I can upgrade to this higher version of the chat bot on the [main chat page](https://chat.openai.com/) or anything the like with my own login from which I did not get that API key. For now, to have the higher GPT4 chat, I need to run `curl` commands in the command line interface or `!curl` commands in a Jupyter Notebook cell.

On the website, I can click on "Upgrade plan"

[image]

and see payment plans:

[image]

But I do not see a way to enter a licensed chat with that API key at hand. If I click on Plus, I need to enter my payment data. If I click on Team, I am asked for the workspace, which I do not have.

If I have an API key from another user, and that API key works in tests against a licensed GPT4 bot by means of shell commands, how can I take that API key to enter the chat with a licensed GPT4 bot for my own user? It would be best if I could do this on the main chat site of Open AI, but I am also fine with other sites and tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Workaround: Ask questions to the chatbot in a Jupyter Notebook cell

I see no way to get this done. Therefore, here is the workaround in Jupyter Notebook how you can ask the chatbot questions with an API token almost like in a chat.

1. The first heading is the curl command which is nothing new and is not like the chat that only answers. It also outputs more metadata.
2. The second heading shows a way how you can shrink down the answer to just the message content.

#### Curl as a shell command in the Jupyter Notebook cell

```
!curl https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer sk-123abc..............................." \
  -d '{\
  "model": "gpt-4",\
  "messages": [\
     {"role": "user", "content": "Give\
      me an example for \
      a model string as the argument \
      for the 'FineTuningJob' \
      parameter '"'model'"'."}]}'
```

Out:

```
{
  "id": "chatcmpl-123abc............................",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "created": 1706123456,
  "model": "gpt-4-0613",
  "choices": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "message": {
        "role": "assistant",
        "content": "\"bert-base-uncased\""
      },
      "logprobs": null,
      "finish_reason": "stop"
    }
  ],
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": 32,
    "completion_tokens": 7,
    "total_tokens": 39
  },
  "system_fingerprint": null
}
```

#### Curl with a dictionary output so that you can show only the message content

##### f-string as the shell input

```
str_curl = f"""curl https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions \\
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \\
  -H "Authorization: Bearer sk-123abc..............................." \\
  -d '{{"model": "gpt-4","messages": [{{"role": "user", "content": "Give\
  me an example for \
  a model string as the argument \
  for the 'FineTuningJob' \
  parameter '"'model'"'."}}]}}'"""
```

Mind that f-strings need to escape curly brackets with double brackets {{, }}, backslashes with double backslashes, but if you just want to make a linebreak inside an item, you do not need two, but just one (!), (two at the end of a line will even throw an error):

> Give\
> me an example for \`

Thus, you need just **one** backslash to wrap the line. My guess: this one backslash seems to be needed only for Jupyter Notebook to read the lines, not for the curl or the chatbot since those do not care about too many spaces that are inside a string. The f-string that begins with """ and ends with """ does not need the slashes as linebreaks, it only goes on and chains altogether.

Replace inline double quotes with single quotes (see `'FineTuningJob'`) or put one single quote before and one after it, like with `'''` or `'"'` (see `'"'model'"'`), to avoid the error:

```
> {'error': {'message': "We could not parse the JSON body of your
> request. (HINT: This likely means you aren't using your HTTP library
> correctly. The OpenAI API expects a JSON payload, but what was sent
> was not valid JSON. If you have trouble figuring out how to fix this,
> please contact us through our help center at help.openai.com.)",  
> 'type': 'invalid_request_error',   'param': None,   'code': None}}
```

You can check how the string looks like and whether the f-string works:

```
print(str_curl)
```

Out:

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer sk-123abc..............................." \
  -d '{"model": "gpt-4","messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Give  me an example for   a model string as the argument   for the 'FineTuningJob'   parameter '"'model'"'."}]}'
```

##### Other string formats to check

You do not need to make strings as Python f-strings. You can also try making the curl command with all of the escapes in the CLI instead. There are tools that can escape your input string so that it becomes a readable curl input string. For Linux, you can find them at [Escape strings sent in curl data when using application/json](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162362/escape-strings-sent-in-curl-data-when-using-application-json).

For curl formatting, I found also [CURL escape single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122586/curl-escape-single-quote) helpful.

##### Run the curl string in the CLI and get its output in Python

With this string at hand, you can run curl in the CLI and still get its output in Python, taken from [Json parsing Python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50303518/11154841):

```
import subprocess
import json

def getProcessOutput(cmd):
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
    data, err = process.communicate()
    if process.returncode is 0:
        return data.decode('utf-8')
    else:
        print("Error:", err)
    return ""

# for domain in getProcessOutput("cat /etc/localdomains").splitlines():
cmd = str_curl
data = getProcessOutput(cmd)
json.loads(data)
```

Out:

```
{'id': 'chatcmpl-abc123......................',
 'object': 'chat.completion',
 'created': 1706123456,
 'model': 'gpt-4-0613',
 'choices': [{'index': 0,
   'message': {'role': 'assistant',
    'content': '"arn:aws:sagemaker:us-west-2:123456789012:model-package/mymodelpackage"'},
   'logprobs': None,
   'finish_reason': 'stop'}],
 'usage': {'prompt_tokens': 32, 'completion_tokens': 24, 'total_tokens': 56},
 'system_fingerprint': None}
```

With that done and loaded into a json dictionary, you can check the mere answer in the json tree with:

```
print(json.loads(data)['choices'][0]['message']['content'])
```

Out:

```
"arn:aws:sagemaker:us-west-2:123456789012:model-package/mymodelpackage"
```